# The resolution is squashed!

Tags: resolution, monitor, 14.10

I just installed Ubuntu 14.10 from the .iso.  It worked fine the first time, but the second time I booted it up, the resolution was really messed up.  The monitor was displaying everything really squashed as if it was a square screen. (It's not)  I looked at the "displays" settings and everything looked okay, but no matter what I tried from the forums and Youtube, it stayed flatter than it should.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I had a similar problem recently with 14.04, reinstalling it worked. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the resolution at the "Display" settings. It worked for me.

Comment: I recommend that you **[edit]** this answer to expand it with more detailed instructions on how to do that.